# Access slot variable or method in Nuxt 3 layout

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am wondering if there is a way to get access to `<NuxtPage />` or `<slot />` variables

I have a layout like this

`custom.vue`

```html
<div>
  <button @click="backButton" />
  <NuxtPage ref="loadedPage" />
  <!-- or -->
  <slot ref="loadedPage" />
</div>
```

and will like to have the function `backButton` be used from the page that was rendered.

I tried using `defineExpose({backButton})` on the page (say `about.vue`) and access it inside the custom.vue as

```js
const loadedPage = ref(null)
onMounted(()=>{
  console.log(loadedPage.value)
})
```

but I can not still access it, also using `useSlots.default()` is not exposing it.

Is it possible to access the `backButton` function?

The functions are from the pages and I will like to access them in layout, I can create the function there because each page handles the function differently.

Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qjeqtb?file=layouts/default.vue

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit, where the function is defined and where you would like to access it? Providing more (minimal) code would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question with reproduction link @some-user

Comment: Why would you want that in the first place? IMO, you can omit reaching for those if you only look on how to achieve a back button. More of a Vue-router thing here.